# ngOnInit not firing one change between children routes

Tags: angular

My app is set up to filter different projects when links are clicked at the top. This done by taking in a route param and then passing it to my component. My component then filters a db query OnInit based on the provided param. This all works fine but the issue I'm running into is the ngOnInit isn't being fired when I move between child routes.

ngDoCheck seems like the thing I'd need to use but this is being fired when the app is being loaded and breaking my code because the projectService isn't completed. Is there a way to force ngDoCheck to wait until the project is loaded before it starts listening? The Angular website states it should already do this but from what I'm seeing it isn't.

Any advice on how I should be implementing this correctly?

Component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.paramsSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.pageCategory = params['id']);
    this.getProjects();
  }

  getProjects() {
    if (this.pageCategory) {
      this.projectService.getProjects()
        .subscribe(
        projects => this.projects = projects.filter(project => project.category.includes(this.pageCategory)),
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    } else {
      this.projectService.getProjects()
        .subscribe(
        projects => this.projects = projects,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
  }
```

Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      component: HomeComponent,
    }]
  },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem why ngOnInit is not called is because Angular is smart about reinitializing components. The trick is that both of your routes are loading the same component (HomeComponent), and Angular sees that and sees now reason why it should destroy the previous one, but would be better and less CPU intensive to just change the parameters for that component (In this case its the Inputs of the components). So there is this lifecyclehook "ngOnChanges" which is called when the inputs of the component are changed. You should listen to this one and than call `this.getProjects()` inside because I assume you are changing the state inside that service.

But I think your problem is a bit diferrent. `this.getProjects()` should be called inside of the `this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe` handler because noone is calling `this.getProjects` except the onInit hook which when called the pageCategory is still NOT assigned to the current route because the subscription comes later because its async. 
You need the subscription handler to call `this.getProjects`.

Hope I helped and clarified some things for you

Comment: Thanks! I was able to take what you said and figure it out. I'm still calling everything from OnInit. OhChanges seems to kill my query request and return nothing.